# How to enable COM port access on Hyper-V VM from host?

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I've installed a windows 10 VM using the windows 11 Hyper-V program. The reason for this is that Windows 11 has caused me a number of problems in my build environment for my QT application, whereas Windows 10 works fine. I have a serial device that I connect via USB to my PC and the program reads the COM port it is on, and connects to the device.

I want to be able to read the COM port on my Hyper-V VM, but can't seem to get it working. In my Hyper-V settings, I have enabled "Named Pipe" for COM 1 and have given it a pipe name of `COM1`. However, when connecting the device on my host (which is on COM3), it is not picked up on the VM.

The only set of clear instructions I can find seem to all relate to connection over the internet when I do not need that. I just need it to pass through from my host -> VM.

Comment: Hyper-V doesn't support COM (nor USB) passthrough without third-party software -  https://serverfault.com/questions/999844/accessing-physical-host-com-port-within-hyper-v-vm - though Remote Desktop does offer COM forwarding which might be an option.